# How to match two columns of inexact text and return value in third?

Tags: excel, vba

I have to match two columns, one has "all_filenames" while the other has the "part_number".

I used VLOOKUP to find matches and it did work.

Under "all_filenames there is around 2,000 data and under "part_number" there are only 500.
The datas under "part_number" could match multiple datas under "all_filenames".
The problem is it does not match the specific name.

Example: Column A would be all_filenames:

```
XP605_Top.jpg  
AR131_Front.jpg  
28528_765BP_Front.jpg  
2543_Front.jpg
```

On Column B would be "part_number":

```
XP605.jpg  
AR131.jpg  
28528.jpg  
2543.jpg
```

This should be considered a match but since there are a few words or number missing from Column A it won't match.

I want to solve this with a UDF.

```vb
Public Function WhereIs(rIn As Range, rList As Range) As String
   Dim s1 As String, r As Range
   Dim s2 As String
   WhereIs = ""
   s1 = rIn.Text

   For Each r In rList
      s2 = r.Text
      If InStr(1, s2, s1) > 0 Then
         If WhereIs = "" Then
            WhereIs = r.Address(0, 0)
         Else
            WhereIs = WhereIs & "," & r.Address(0, 0)
         End If
      End If
   Next r

   If WhereI <> "" Then WhereIs = "no match" 
      
End Function
```

This is the only code I've found. It does not match because I think it tries to look for an exact match.

I need the 'match value' to return in another column with the part number and if there are multiple matches I need all of it to be in the column.

Comment: Hi @braX I've included the code. Thank you.

Comment: Have try VLookUp's exact match as FALSE ? For ex. =VLOOKUP(What you want to look up, where you want to look for it, the column number in the range containing the value to return, return an Approximate or Exact match – indicated as 1/TRUE, or 0/FALSE).

Comment: Hi @ChinmayT yes I have tried Vlookup already and it did match a lot of the data. The problem I have is that some data do repeat with an additional number in the end indicating it's another angle of the picture, but it won't match just because of the additional number and I've used TRUE as well and it just returns a lot of incorrect matches.

Comment: Three functions that may help: REPLACE("XP605.jpg AR131.jpg 28528.jpg 2543.jpg", ".jpg", "") to remove all ".jpg" from the parts list;  and Dim v as variant: v=SPLIT("XP605 AR131 28528 2543", " ") to turn the parts list into an array v(0)="XP605" v(1)="AR131", v(2)="28528" v(3)="2543", which you can then loop over with For i = LBound(v) to UBound(v):   'try to match v(i) : Next,  using IF InStr("XP605_Top.jpg AR131_Front.jpg 28528_765BP_Front.jpg 2543_Front.jpg", v(i)) > 0 THEN 'matched

Answer (score 0):

You could just use LEFT and FIND to clean up your columns of data. If your filenames are in column A then

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND("_",A1)-1)
```

Will remove everything up to the first "_".
For your parts list

```
=LEFT(C1,LEN(C1)-4)
```

will get rid of the ".jpg" portion of the name (or you could use REPLACE as suggested in the comments). This will make the VLOOKUP function happier